# Django built in auth views for password reset - Form not showing

Tags: python, django, passwords, change-password

I am trying to use the django.contrib.auth views to allow website users to reset their password. However, the email field for users to enter their email address to reset password is not showing. The form tag is showing instead:

This is how it looks like
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Yp9l.png)

The following is what I have implemented, mainly only changes made in urls.py and templates. How can I solve this error? Thank you.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.contrib.auth import views as authViews

urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^account/password_reset/$', authViews.password_reset, {'template_name' : 'accounts/reset_password.html' }, name='password_reset'),
    re_path(r'^account/password_reset/done/$', authViews.password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
    re_path(r'^account/reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', authViews.password_reset_confirm, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password_confirm.html'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),
    re_path(r'^account/reset/done/$', authViews.password_reset_complete, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

reset_password.html

```
<p class="text-center">If you have forgotten your password, please type your email address so we can send you a reset link.</p>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <p> {‌{ form | crispy }} </p>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mb-3 float-right">Reset Password</button>
    </form>
```

And the forms.py file is below, although I don't think it's related. Additional information, just in case.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Product, Category
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='eg. youremail@anyemail.com')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','password1','password2')

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('name','slug','description','category','price','image','stock','available')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you load the crispy form tag? include `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` in your `reset_password.html`

Comment: I believe the issue relates to the template or crispy form cuz the form tag is showing up in the page. To confirm this try to remove crispy tag and see if the form field will show up. Use {{form}} only.

Comment: I tried that too, but it's still returning errors. I uploaded the code in github at https://github.com/moonfairyz/sun 
Hope you could help me with it. Thank you.

Comment: There's no mistake in your code, the template engine reads {{form|crispy}} as a plain text, I deleted and re-wrote the same and it worked. re write {{form|crispy}} with curly braces and it will work, don't copy and paste it.

Comment: it worked beautifully as you said. It is weird. Is there a way to avoid such bugs without having to retype? Especially when you're testing code and modifying here and there, it's hard not to do some copy and pasting sometimes.
THANK YOU for everything. You're a life saviour!

Comment: Actually it's a weird bug, I believe the curly braces caused it. However, you won't receive such a bug in the future but as a good practice avoid to copy paste as much as you can. glad to hear your issue has been sorted out.